# Using a Limit at Zero to Evaluate a Limit at Infinity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, trigonometry, epsilon-delta

When does the following hold?

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(\frac{1}{x})$

Why? Assume the right-hand side limit exists. An example of such a function would be $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

Motivation: I would like to show that

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x \sin (\frac{1}{x})=1$.

If I can justify using

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x\sin (\frac{1}{x})=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\sin (x)}{x}$,

this will yield the desired result as

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\sin (x)}{x}=1$.

Thank you :)

Comment: **Hint**: prove $$x\to \infty \implies {1\over x}\to 0$$

Comment: Whatever happens with $f(x) $ as $x\to\infty $ exactly the same thing happens with $f(1/x)$ as $x\to 0^{+}$. This is a special case of rule of substitution in limits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my proof that

$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) =L$

if and only if

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(\frac{1}{x})=L$.

We begin by showing that if $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) =L$ then $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(\frac{1}{x})=L$.

Correspondingly, suppose $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) =L$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $N > 0$ such that if $x>N>0$, then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ (here we are making use of the definition of a limit at infinity). Note that $x>N>0$ is equivalent to $0<\frac{1}{x}<\frac{1}{N}$. Let $u=\frac{1}{x}$ and $\delta = \frac{1}{N}$. It follows that if $0<u<\delta$, then $|f(\frac{1}{u})-L|<\epsilon$. As $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, it follows that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(\frac{1}{x})=L$.

We will now show that if $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(\frac{1}{x})=L$ then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) =L$.

Correspondingly, suppose that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(\frac{1}{x})=L$.

Let $\epsilon >0$. Choose $\delta>0$ such that if $0<x<\delta$, then $|f(\frac{1}{x})-L|<\epsilon$ (here we are making use of the definition of a limit). Note that $0<x<\delta$ is equivalent to $\frac{1}{x}>\frac{1}{\delta}>0$. Let $u=\frac{1}{x}$ and $N=\frac{1}{\delta}$. It follows that if $u>N>0$, then $|f(u)-L|<\epsilon$. As $\epsilon >0$ was arbitrary, it follows that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=L$.

This completes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

For **any** function $f$ on $(0,\infty)$, $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists iff $\lim_{x \to 0+} f(\frac 1  x)$ exists and the limits are equal in this case.

Comment: Do you know where I can find a proof of this?

Comment: Just write down the definitions of the two limits and see if you can prove it yourself. If you  get stuck I will be glad to help.

Comment: What do you think of the proof I have posted?

Comment: It is perfect. So you didn't need any help for this! I have given your proof a +1.

Comment: I was trying for a long time before I posted here. For some reason it only just clicked :)